# Kubernetes statefulset replication

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, kubernetes-statefulset

I am using kubernetes  statefulset for my mongodb and influxdb.

[image]

`In summary, StatefulSets provide the following advantages when compared to Deployment objects: Ordered numbers for each Pod. The first Pod can be a primary, which makes it a good choice when creating a replicated database setup, which handles both reading and writing. Other Pods act as replicas.`

But while i am deploying statefulset for both mongodb and influxdb with 3 replicas, only one pod (first pod, i.e. mondodb-0 and influxdb-0) is storing the data, non of the remaining pods are cloning the data from the first pod.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: influxdb
  labels:
    app: influxdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb
  serviceName: influxdb
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: influxdb
        image: influxdb:1.8.10
        command:
                # - influx
                # - --bind_ip_all
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
        env:
         - name: INFLUXDB_USERNAME
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: influxdb-secret
               key: influxdb-username
         - name: INFLUXDB_PASSWORD
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: influxdb-secret
               key: influxdb-password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: influxdb-volume
          mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: influxdb-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ ReadWriteOnce ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 25Gi
```

I am trying with the above yaml file, but i am unable to clone the data from first pod to the remaining pods. only one pod is getting the data.

Comment: Do you run it in a clustered setup?

Comment: @Jonas, i am using AWS EKS setup, with 2 worker nodes

Comment: @Rakesh Any updates on this ?? I have similar use case. If its solved can you share me yaml scripts. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In statefulset, each instance runs independently. So in your template, `influxdb-0`, `influxdb-1`, and `influxdb-2` individually runs the `**influxdb:1.8.10**`
with the credentials you provided. If you need to pre-fill the database or recover from a snapshot it shouldn't be dependant on the previous pods but it should be part of each instance of the statefulset (e.g., through initContainer or a script in your configs or app that connects to db and provide neccassary data if it's needed)